# in mutate (dplyr) - treating a few columns as a row vector

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

I have a data frame with several columns which represent coefficients in a certain equation. I want to evaluate this equation and add it to the dataframe (e.g. row by row computation). but to evaluate the equation I need all the coeficients as a row vector. here is an example:

```
d = data.frame(id = 1:2,name=c("a","b"),
               c1 = 3:4,c2=5:6,c3=2:3,
               x1=1:2,x2=7:8,x3=3:2)
```

I need to evaluate c1*x1+c2*x2+x3*x3, but typing in the exact equation is not practical. in the real case there are dozens of them. Ideally I would like to select them and treat them as row vectors, something like that:

```
# not a real code, but a wishful thinkg
d %>% mutate(result = sum((select(starts_with(c)) %>% as.vector)*
                           select(starts_with(x)) %>% as.vector)
                      )
             )
```

This of course doesn't work like that, but I wonder if you know of any way to treat a group of columns as a row vector when doing a row-by-row computation as in mutate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to `gather` the data frame as follows. The result is in the `CX` column.

```
library(tidyverse)

d2 <- d %>%
  gather(Type, Value, -id, -name) %>%
  separate(Type, into = c("Letter", "Number"), sep = 1) %>%
  spread(Letter, Value) %>%
  mutate(CX = c * x) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(CX = sum(CX))
d2
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   name     CX
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 a        44
# 2 b        62
```

And here is an option with `dplyr`. However, you have to make sure the order of your column is correct if you want to use this solution.

```
dc <- d %>% select(starts_with("c"))
dx <- d %>% select(starts_with("x"))
d3 <- dc * dx 
d4 <- bind_cols(d %>% select(id, name), d3) %>% mutate(CX = rowSums(d3))
d4
#   id name c1 c2 c3 CX
# 1  1    a  3 35  6 44
# 2  2    b  8 48  6 62
```

And here is the base R equivalent of the above code.

```
dc <- d[, grepl("^c", names(d))]
dx <- d[, grepl("^x", names(d))]
d3 <- dc * dx 
d3$CX <- rowSums(d3)
d4 <- cbind(d[, c("id", "name")], d3)
d4
#   id name c1 c2 c3 CX
# 1  1    a  3 35  6 44
# 2  2    b  8 48  6 62
```

Answer (score 1):

With `nest` and `map` you can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(cx = map_dbl(data, ~ sum(select(.x, starts_with("c")) * select(.x, starts_with("x")))))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      id data                cx
#   <int> <list>           <dbl>
# 1     1 <tibble [1 x 7]>    44
# 2     2 <tibble [1 x 7]>    62
```

Alternatively you can use `do` so that the dataframe can be used as an input:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(mutate(., cx = sum(select(., starts_with("c")) * select(., starts_with("x")))))

# A tibble: 2 x 9
# Groups:   id [2]
#      id name     c1    c2    c3    x1    x2    x3    cx
#   <int> <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1 a         3     5     2     1     7     3    44
# 2     2 b         4     6     3     2     8     2    62
```

To make sure the correct products are taken (i.e. x1*c1 and not x1*c2) you can first extract the maximum number that is available for both x and c and then use this to get the correct column matching:

```
col_numbers <- d %>% select(matches("^(x|c)")) %>% names() %>% parse_number() 
max_col_number <- which.max(col_numbers[duplicated(col_numbers)])

d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(mutate(., cx = sum(select(., str_c("c", seq_len(max_col_number))) * select(., str_c("x", seq_len(max_col_number))))))
```

Or you can first arrange the columns and then use the approach from above:

```
d <- select(d, id, name, sort(current_vars()))

d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(mutate(., cx = sum(select(., starts_with("c")) * select(., starts_with("x")))))
```